# Scroll doesn't work in container div on iOS 15 Safari iPhone

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, scroll

I have been struggling with it for some time and I don't know how to do it ... I have tried various methods but no results.

I want the container `#box .zbox` to scroll, not the entire website.
It's mainly about iOS and iPhone, I tested Chrome and Safari on iOS15 and it doesn't work, on Android Chrome it works, desktop works as well.

Below is a simplified version of my website.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
I just want to achieve something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u40Sj.png)

I tried a lot of things, 101% container inside, some css rules, iscroll.js , i wrote js with scrollTop and touchmove listener, but all without results.. is it achievable?

Checked macOS with iOS agent inspector, but it works there... only on iPhone not working (checked iOS 15 & 14)..

```css
body,
html {
  color: #333;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

#box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11;
}

#box .zbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute; /* absolute or fixed only */
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #0e0e0e;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

footer {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #0e0e0e;
  color: #fff;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 15;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <nav>
      NAVIGATION
    </nav>
      
    <main class="container">
      <div id="box">
        <article class="zbox">
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
          <p>SCROLLABLE CONTENT</p>
        </article>
      </div>
    </main>
      
    <footer>
        FOOTER
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```